# Trouble configuring and connecting to remote Git repository

Tags: git, git-extensions

I am trying to properly set up my Git repositories on a remote server so that I can push from my local repositories on my computer.  I installed Git and Redmine on my CentOS server so that I could host my own code repositories.  Unfortunately this entire project of mine started out a bit messy because it was originally a test to see how easily I could get this service set up, but after *finally* getting Redmine working, I wanted to see if I could get it functional without having to start over from scratch.

On my server, I have Redmine installed at /public_html/redmine/, but since I created this account in cPanel, I went in and edited my Apache VirtualHost entry so that /public_html/redmine/public/ is my document root so that Redmine would show up.  Yes, I would have installed differently if I had to do it over again.

Anyway, now I have Git installed on my Windows 7 box and am able to use TortoiseGit to create a repository in my VS project folder.  I am trying to use Git Extensions to manage my repositories here, as well as on my server, but I cannot seem to get the remote connection configured correctly.  I know the repository works on the server because it shows properly in Redmine.

My problem is that I cannot figure out exactly where my problem is.  I do not know if it is how I am trying to connect to the server, or if my server or remote repository is not configured correctly.  My git_repo folder is currently in /redmine/public/.  I have tried using the GUI remote repository function in Git Extensions and the command line, following the instructions in numerous places, and have gotten all sorts of errors all saying I cannot connect.

I would really appreciate any help trying to troubleshoot this as I am seriously burned out from staring at my computer all day trying to get this up and running.

Just as a starting point:

In Git Extensions, I enter user@hostname:redmine/public/git_repo/project/.git (just like the instructions) and I get:

"Fetching origin
Done
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: Could not fetch origin"

That is the most common error I get with all of my different attempts.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Step 1. Forget about using git extensions. Use msysgit from the command line. It will be easier for you to see what's going on.
Step 2. Set up ssh keys on both machines. Don't use a password when creating the key. add the -t rsa option on ssh-keygen.

Report back here when you have cloned your repository using bare msysgit from the command line.

I've been happily using MSysGit for a number of years now and never needed to go to git extensions.

Comment: Okay, I got rid of Git Extensions and installed MSysGit.  I then created keys in both places and added my pub key info to the server file. 

In the console, I ran 
`git remote add origin user@host.com:redmine/public/git_repo/project/.git` and then `git push origin master`

But I keep getting the "does not appear to be a git repository" and "The remote end hung up unexpectedly" errors.

Comment: I got it fixed.  My problem was that I was assuming that the starting directory path for my domain was after public_html, but I guess not.  I added it to the remote path and it connected and pushed correctly.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Glad it worked out. Sorry for not catching your earlier comment in time.

Comment: @jb11: Based on your comment above it seems the problem was not with Git Extensions.  Nothing wrong with msysgit but Git Extensions is an excellent tool.  FWIW, you can even configure it to run using msysgit (so that when it opens a bash window you are using msysgit).  As for connecting to networked locations, I have found that Git Extensions does better with mapped drives (versus UNC paths).

Comment: This answer is completely unhelpful. The OP had a valid question about using a particular (highly popular) technology. Simply stating "don't use that, use something else instead" doesn't help at all.